# How to link an image from folder in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem in which my picture won't display on my page when I try to link it. I have it in my folder. Is Wordpress maybe making a problem or? It's my first time making a Wordpress theme from scratch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC0jN.png)

Comment: You are requesting a relative image and you need to make it absolute, see this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/667/12496

Comment: Or properly relative may work too I guess? `./img/logo.jpg`

Comment: Please include code instead of pictures, it's better for readers